# Really bad scrolling performance of FlatList when using stickyHeaderIndices on Android

Tags: android, react-native, performance, expo, react-native-flatlist

I'm using React Native (with Expo) and I have this code:

```
<FlatList
    scrollEventThrottle={16}
    stickyHeaderIndices={[1]}
    data={categories}
    renderItem={renderCategory}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
/>
```

that is used to render a quite large (300+) product list, with quality images on most of the products.

The performance is arguably perfect on all devices apart from a lower-end Android device (running Android 12). Here, it's only perfect when removing the `stickyHeaderIndices` attribute from FlatList (which is needed to make the search bar sticky). If `stickyHeaderIndices` is used, the scrolling takes a huge performance hit.

- Without `stickyHeaderIndices` (good scrolling performance):  
  https://streamable.com/w59j6a
- With `stickyHeaderIndices` (bad scrolling performance): 
  https://streamable.com/o74oc5

Has anyone encountered such an issue with `stickyHeaderIndices` before and/or any idea how to improve the performance of this scenario?

Thanks.

Comment: Performance is always an issue with lower end android devices when using Flatlist. Consider using `react-native-fast-image` and `FlashList` and see if it helps.

Comment: Links in question is dead

Comment: Are they? They seem to work for me, even in incognito